# Critical values and critical points of the mapping $z\mapsto z^2 + \bar{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

This question is from a math-essentials booklet for physicists. The function is not analytic from the C-R conditions but that is all I know.

$ \rlap{\textbf{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}}{\mbox{Its derivative should be}}$ $2z + 2\bar{z} =4Re[z]$ So are its critical points all over the real axis?

The question also asks for a roiugh sketch of the graph. How would I sketch $(x,y)\mapsto (x+x^2-y^2,2xy-y)$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by its derivative? $\bar{z}$ is not complex differentiable.

Comment: @Alex I thought critical values were where the derivative of the function goes to zero i.e extremal and inflection points. I would correct the mistake, though I am even more lost now.

Comment: @Approximist: That's the definition for real functions and I believe for holomorphic complex functions as well. In this context, however, I have no idea what the definition would be.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This problem has nothing to do with complex analysis. We just have a map
$$f:\  {\mathbb R}^2\to{\mathbb R}^2, \quad (x,y)\mapsto (u,v):=(x+x^2-y^2, 2xy-y).$$
The graph of this map lives in ${\mathbb R}^4$ and so is of no help in visualizing $f$. I suggest drawing images of some lines $x=$const. (horizontal parabolas) and $y=$const. (again horizontal parabolas). Along the circle $x^2+y^2={1\over4}$ the Jacobian of $f$ vanishes; this will lead to special effects in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

About the second question: here are some nice ways to plot complex functions: http://www.maa.org/pubs/amm_complements/complex.html , 
http://www.mai.liu.se/~halun/complex/ , 
http://www1.math.american.edu/People/lcrone/ComplexPlot.html

Or http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+z%5E2+%2B+Conj%5Bz%5D

Comment: thanks for the links. In addition, Terry Tao has some java pplets on his coursepage for complex mappings. This question however is from a math-essentials booklet for physicists from the 70s, and I think its intention is that the student should be able to draw a rough sketch without referring to computers.

Comment: New link: http://users.mai.liu.se/hanlu09/complex/